# HY000 The prepared statement contains a stored routine call that refers to that same statement

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor

When i exec `call P_AGINGDATA('xxx');`. I get the error below:

```
Error Code: 1444 
The prepared statement contains a stored routine call that refers to that same statement. It's not allowed to execute a prepared statement in such a recursive manner
```

Error message says that i cannot call a routine which refers to the same statement. But i didn't !

It made me headache. **Who can give me some advice?**

**procedure i directly call**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_AGINGDATA 
--
DECLARE CUR_AGING CURSOR FOR
SELECT ID,
       TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       AGING_OPTION,
       MAX_RESERVE_DAY,
       HISTORY_TABLE_NAME
  FROM t_cm_aging_config T
 WHERE T.RULE_VALID = 1
 ORDER BY ID;
  OPEN CUR_AGING;
  loop_label:
  LOOP
    FETCH CUR_AGING
      INTO V_ID, V_TABLE_NAME, V_COLUMN_NAME, V_AGING_OPTION, V_MAX_RESERVE_DAY, V_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME;
    IF NOT_FOUND = 1 THEN 
        LEAVE loop_label; 
    END IF;
      IF UPPER(V_AGING_OPTION) IN ('HISTORY', 'DELETE') THEN
         -- todo
      ELSEIF UPPER(V_AGING_OPTION) = 'EXECUTE' THEN
        SET @GetName = CONCAT('CALL ',V_TABLE_NAME,'(',V_MAX_RESERVE_DAY,');');
        PREPARE stmt FROM @GetName;
        EXECUTE stmt;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
      END IF;
  END LOOP loop_label;
  CLOSE CUR_AGING;
END $$
```

**another procedure called within a loop of previous procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE P_CM_AGING_CUSTOMER ( IN v_max_reserve_day BIGINT )
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_days_from_1970         BIGINT;
    DECLARE v_start_unix_timestamp   BIGINT;
    DECLARE v_has_exception   INT;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET v_has_exception = 1;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TMP_OFFERING_INST_ID (OFFERING_INST_ID BIGINT(13));
    TRUNCATE TABLE TMP_OFFERING_INST_ID;

    SET @Insertofferinst = CONCAT('INSERT INTO TMP_OFFERING_INST_ID select offering_inst_id from t_cm_offer_inst t where status=''9'' and ACTIVE_FLAG=''0'' and '
     , ' CREATED_TIME < 86400000*(',ifnull(v_days_from_1970, ''),' - ',ifnull(v_max_reserve_day, ''),') and not exists (select 1 from t_cm_offer_inst a where t.customer_id=a.customer_id and (a.status<>''9'' or a.ACTIVE_FLAG<>''0''))');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @Insertofferinst;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    COMMIT;

    -- related data inserted into tmp table,start delete data
    SET @Deletedata = 'DELETE FROM T_CM_OFFER_INST_FEE WHERE OFFERING_INST_ID IN (SELECT OFFERING_INST_ID FROM TMP_OFFERING_INST_ID)';
    PREPARE stmt FROM @Deletedata;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    COMMIT;
END;
$$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Error says

> The prepared statement contains a stored routine call that refers to
>   that same statement.

You have already prepared STMT.
Change the variable name that is to be executed, try with

```
PREPARE newSTMT  FROM @GetName;
EXECUTE newSTMT ;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE newSTMT ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I find that the prepared statement which calls routine is not correct.

```
ELSEIF UPPER(V_AGING_OPTION) = 'EXECUTE' THEN
    SET @GetName = CONCAT('CALL ',V_TABLE_NAME,'(',V_MAX_RESERVE_DAY,');');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @GetName;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

The syntax below is correct,

```
ELSEIF UPPER(V_AGING_OPTION) = 'EXECUTE' THEN
    SET @procedur = V_TABLE_NAME;
    SET @Getname = CONCAT('CALL ',@procedur,'(?)');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @Getname;
    SET @paramete = V_MAX_RESERVE_DAY;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @paramete; 
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```